# Is there a good, performant unsigned BigInteger type for C#?

Tags: c#, biginteger, unsigned

I'm familiar with the System.Numerics.BigInteger class, but in my app, I'm only ever dealing with positive integers. Negative integers are an error case, and it'd be nice if there was an unsigned equivalent of the BigInteger type so I could remove all of these checks. Does one exist?

Comment: @Splendor: I don't think that's really what's being asked...

Comment: Thanks Jon. I have removed my comments.

Comment: I don't understand why you would say (a) that negative numbers are an error case and that (b) you want to make an unsigned type, that would, then, do what? Raise an exception if you try to assign a negative value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the framework, no. I would try to centralize the checks in as small a public API as possible, and then treat the data as valid for the rest of the time - just as you would for something like null checking. Of course, you still need to be careful if you perform any operations which could *create* a negative value (e.g. subtracting one from another).

You may be able to make the code slightly neater by creating an extension method, e.g.

```
public static void ThrowIfNegative(this BigInteger value, string name)
{
    if (value.Sign < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(name);
    }
}
```

... and use it like this:

```
input.ThrowIfNegative("input");
```

You could potentially create your own `UBigInteger` struct which contained a `BigInteger`, and perform operations between different values by using the `BigInteger` implementation and checks, but I suspect that would be quite a lot of work for relatively little benefit, and *may* have performance implications if you're using it for a lot of calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's have a look at a simple example

```
        uint a=1;
        uint b=2;
        uint c=a-b;
        Console.WriteLine(c);
```

gives you the output `4294967295` (=2^32-1).

But what if you had an unsigned BigInteger with similar behaviour?

```
        UBigInteger a(1);
        UBigInteger b(2);
        UBigInteger c=a-b;
        Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
```

What should that be? Of course, from what you wrote one can assume you might expect to get some kind of exception in this case, but such behaviour would not be consistent to `int`. Better introduce the checks for < 0 where you need them, for example, like the way Jon Skeet suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you only use a reasonably small subset of the the BigInteger API, writing your own wrapper class is easy if laborious.  Here is some sample code to demonstrate that it needn't be that big an operation:

```
public struct UnsignedBigInteger
{
    private BigInteger value;
    private UnsignedBigInteger(BigInteger n) { value = n; }

    public UnsignedBigInteger(uint n) { value = new BigInteger(n); }
    // ... other constructors ...

    public static UnsignedBigInteger operator+(UnsignedBigInteger lhs, UnsignedBigInteger rhs)
    {
        return new UnsignedBigInteger(lhs.value + rhs.value);
    }
    public static UnsignedBigInteger operator-(UnsignedBigInteger lhs, UnsignedBigInteger rhs)
    {
        var result = lhs.value - rhs.value;
        if (result < BigInteger.Zero) throw new InvalidOperationException("value out of range");
        return new UnsignedBigInteger(result);
    }
    // ... other operators ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If negative values present such a problem, is possible to eliminate them somehow so that bad data(the negative values) doesn't even reach your logic ? This will eliminate the check all together. Could you post a short snippet of what you are doing ?

Answer (score -3):

There isn't any support in the framework to declare `BigInteger` as `unsigned`. However, you could create a static method to check if the number is negative or not.

```
public static void ValidateBigIntForUnsigned(BigInteger bigInteger)
{
   if(bigInteger.Sign < 0)
       throw new Exception("Only unsigned numbers are allowed!");
}
```

Comment: I think you're thinking of T-SQL's `BigInt`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx If so, then `System.Numerics.BigInteger` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(VS.100).aspx is not it... it's more like varint(max) if there were such a type.

Comment: @lasseespeholt Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.aspx.

Comment: `System.Numerics.BigInteger` is an arbitrary length integer - not 64 bit as you think. They may share name, but they are not equivalent. It´s in SQL it´s called `BigInt`.

Comment: Ok my mistake, I thought he was talking about TSql BigInt.